# Jersey Restful Services - Unable to connect to server

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I am learning to implement restful webservices with Jersey. I always get "POST

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/welcome/post
```

returned a response status of 404 Not Found" - What is wrong with my code below? Context root on the server side is rest and I have @Path welcome at class level and @pPath post at method level.

**Client**

```
public class WelcomeRestJsonClient {

    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    public void send() {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getClasses().add(com.restclient.MyJsonProvider.class);
        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/rest/welcome/post");
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, myObject);
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
@Path("/welcome")
public class WelcomeRestJson {

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Consumes("application/json")

    public String processPostData(MyObject myObject) {
        System.out.println("Inside processPostData");
        return "success";
    }
 }
```

Am I facing this problem because of incorrect JsonProvider configuration? On the client side, I am using MyJsonProvider which extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider to convert MyObject to Json. My code on the server side simply accepts MyObject. Do I need some code to hook up Json provider on server side too?

Here is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I can access rest index.html. I see the following in the log file.
INFO: Root resource classes found: class com.rest.WelcomeRestJson
I removed "/" with the path. Still same 404 error. Please help.

Comment: What is the mapping of Jersey servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding Jersey Servlet to `web.xml`, get with no parameter started working. But post still failed. Adding the following init parameter to Jersey Servlet and replacing the Jersey Servlet mapping from `/rest/*` to `/*` fixed the issue.

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Do not use slash(/) in path (`@Path("/welcome")`) annotation, instead of that write `@Path("welcome")` and `@Path("post")`.
- I suggest you not to use service name `post` as i could be reserved keyword. Instead of post use `@Path("test")` or something else.
- Use firefox plugin [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) to test your service status to verify is everything fine at service side. It is 404 error, Its not related to json error, Simply Your service is not available at `http://localhost:8080/rest/welcome/post`. Its not about code, its about configuration.
- Are you able to reach upto `http://localhost:8080/rest/` ?

Answer (score 0):

1) It seems that you didn't register your resource. Do you rely on Jersey's autoscanning? It may not work correctly on some environments. The preferred way is to use the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class, since it's a standard JAX-RS way.

2) You need to register your provider also. The preferred way is to use the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class, since it's a standard JAX-RS way.

2.1) Anyway not registering a provider is not a reason for getting 404. Actually I don't remember what error code you'll get, probably it will be 500.

3) Strong advise: check Jetty log. It prints a lot of information containing the list of all registered resources and providers (including default and custom).